# Vite: npm run dev works but build shows TypeError on render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vite

I have a Vite Project which is working fine in local when I run the **npm run dev** command.

Here is the script section from my package.json file

```
"scripts": {
  "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "vite build",
  "preview": "vite preview"
}
```

My vite.config.js file below

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "./",
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

However, if I'm trying to build for production using **npm run build** and **npm run preview**, the page doesn't load anything but only shows a white screen and I get a JS error as below screenshot.
[image: Attached Error Screenshot]

Comment: Can you also attach your vite.config.js file?

Comment: @IP002 Attached my vite.config.js file in the original question

Comment: Did you check your imports? Are you importing something using `import * from ...`? Also are you using node?

Comment: @IP002 I double checked and I haven't done any import * from ... also I am using node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the issue was.
I am using a text animation library **react-animated-text-content** in my project.
This library runs fine in dev on localhost but it fails on build. Other people have run into similar issue and a bug has been logged on Github: https://github.com/kalkson/react-animated-text-content/issues/6

Removing this component resolved the problem